# How do you split a list of dictionaries into separate dictionaries?

Tags: python, dictionary, unnest

How do you split a list of dictionaries into separate dictionaries?

```
dict_example = [{'limited': 1, 'all': 16, 'concept': 1, 'secondly': 1}, {'hello': 3, 'bye': 6}]
```

The desired output:

```
dict_1: {'limited': 1, 'all': 16, 'concept': 1, 'secondly': 1}
dict_2: {'hello': 3, 'bye': 6}
```

Comment: You mean combine a list of dictionaries into 1?

Comment: No into two dictionaries. In dict_example, there are two dictionaries.

Comment: Yes, but the expected output would not be `all` and `bye`??

Comment: `dict_1, dict_2 = dict_example`

Comment: It appears that your question is simply a matter of knowing how to reference individual list locations.  If you search in your browser for "Python list tutorial", you'll find references that can explain this much better than we can manage here.  This is not a intro or tutorial site.

Answer (score -1):

`dict_1, dict_2 = dict_example`.

Comment: In the example I only have two dictionaries, let's say I had a list of 50 dictionaries,  is there an easier way to write it out so that it's not I'm writing dict_1, dict_2 ...dict_50?

Comment: @happydave do you really think this deserves an answer? I've seen downvotes raining for less than this...

Comment: @julien, I have no objection to closing the question, but as long as it's there, it's easy enough to give the answer

Comment: @evc, the way to avoid declaring 50 dictionary variables is to store them in a list :)